# Will twisted pairs aid/hinder or be superfluous?

Tags: twisted-pair

I am making up two looms, each with four cables of 1.2 mm CSA cable. The cables are to activate four 24 V solenoids. Cable runs approx. 4 meters. The two off cables will connect to two off bulk-mounted 4-pin sockets and the rear of the sockets will run to the four off solenoids.

I was toying with the idea of making one loom comprise of the four off positive supplies, but twisting pairs. Then connecting the four wires to connector A, whilst the other loom, will be made of the four off negative wires and connect to connector B.

Apart from making a stiffer cable run, would I gain any benefit from the twisted pairs, or would I create more issues?

Each cable will be enclosed in an adhesive heatshrink with the connector ends sealed as the cable is external to a submersible.

Comment: In absence of any extenuating factors: it won't matter in any meaningful way. (I would just as well assume you left any out because you're aware of the possibilities and none apply here; you are welcome to correct this assumption.)

Comment: If you do chose twisted pairs, you want to twist the hot (+24 V ?) to a given solenoid and it's return together.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information for a meaningful answer.

One reason to use twisted pair, rather than straight cabling, is to reduce electromagnetic radiation. Solenoid switching can produce significant transients, creating EMI (electromagnetic  interference).

*Are there nearby critical sensitive circuits which might be affected*, such as high-gain amplifiers or RF receivers? *Are there snubbers and diodes* in the solenoid circuits? *How close* are the sensitive circuits? Are they *inside additional shielding*?

Depending on those answers, a flat run might work, or twisted pair, or in some cases, the solenoid wiring might even need to use double shielded cables.